# Building a multi input and multi output model: giving AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am newbie to deep learning and trying to build the multi input and multi output model using keras functional API in R and getting this error.

> My code

```r
build_model <- function() {
    ### motif module

    # motif module input
    motif_module_input <- layer_input(shape = ncol(x_train_motif_module), name = 'motif_module_input')

    motif_module <- motif_module_input %>%
        layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu') %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
        layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu') %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
        layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu') %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
        layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu')

    motif_module_output <- motif_module %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'motif_module_output')

    #SVM_input <- layer_input(shape = c(2), name = 'SVM_input')

    ### DNA module
    # DNA module input
    DNA_module_input <- layer_input(shape = c(user_img_rows, user_img_cols), name = 'DNA_module_input')

    DNA_module <- DNA_module_input %>%
        layer_conv_1d(filters = 128, kernel_size = 7, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(user_img_rows, user_img_cols)) %>%
        layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 4, strides = 2) %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%

        layer_conv_1d(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(user_img_rows, user_img_cols)) %>%
        layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 8, strides = 4) %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%

        layer_flatten() %>%
        layer_dense(units  = 128, activation  = 'relu') 

    DNA_module_output <- DNA_module %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'DNA_module_output')


    main_output <- layer_concatenate(c(motif_module, DNA_module)) %>%  
        layer_dense(units = 16, activation = 'relu') %>%
        layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'relu') %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'main_output')


    model <- keras_model(
        inputs = c(motif_module_input, DNA_module_input), 
        outputs = c(motif_module_output, DNA_module_output, main_output)
    )

    model %>% compile(
        loss = list(motif_module_output = 'binary_crossentropy', DNA_module_output = 'binary_crossentropy', main_output = 'binary_crossentropy'),
        loss_weights = list(motif_module_output = 0.5, DNA_module_output = 0.5, main_output = 1),
        optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = 1e-06),
        metrics   = c('accuracy')
    )

    model

}

model <- build_model()
# training the model
# Display training progress by printing a single dot for each completed epoch.
print_dot_callback <- callback_lambda(
    on_epoch_end = function(epoch, logs) {
        if (epoch %% 80 == 0) cat("\n")
        cat(".")
    }
) 

# The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement.
early_stop <- callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 5, restore_best_weights = FALSE)

# model <- build_model()
history <- model %>% fit(
    x = list(motif_module_input = x_train_motif_module, DNA_module_input = x_train_DNA_module),
    y = list(motif_module_output = y_train_DNA_module, DNA_module_output = y_train_DNA_module, main_output = y_train_DNA_module),
    epochs = user_epochs,
    validation_split = user_validation_split,
    batch_size = user_batch_size, 
    use_multiprocessing = TRUE,
    verbose = 2,
    callbacks = list(early_stop, print_dot_callback)
)
```

> This results in error py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'shape'

Can some one help me understand the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error is resulting due to the input data format. One of my input data is data frame and when converted to matrix type it worked fine.

Hope it helps others.